# How to get Distance on google map circle?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have done this

[image: I have created this Circle in Android by using google map API..]

i want this

[image: Now i want to add the distance text within the circle]

I am able to create a cirlce but i want to plot some radius text within the circle if you have any clues plz help me i am using google api for android..

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is use addPlyline method to draw line and can create a custom marker to show distance.

to draw line :

```
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
  .add(new LatLng(lats, lons), new LatLng(late,lone))
  .width(5)
  .color(color));
```

To create a custom marker:

```
 map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(<Add a LatLng of center>)
        .title("100 Mi"));
```

To infowindow at activity loads :

For that you need to create a Marker instead of using a map.addMarker use this.

```
LatLng latlng= new LatLng(lat, lng);
    Marker marker= map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                             .position(latlng)
                              .title("100 Mi"));
    marker.showInfoWindow();
```

Use ondraw method to draw text on map :

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
strokePaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
strokePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
strokePaint.setTextSize(16);
strokePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

Paint textPaint = new Paint();
textPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
textPaint.setTextSize(16);
textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

canvas.drawText("Some Text", 100, 100, strokePaint);
canvas.drawText("Some Text", 100, 100, textPaint);

super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
}
```

Comment: but it is invoking after clicking on the marker and i need only when activity will load.

Comment: didnt get that. so you are creating circle at activity loads?

Comment: there is a  button which is fetching latlong from server and plot that points to the map with some geo-fence(Circle) and markers.

Comment: well if you want to draw a circle at activity load then you will need the LatLong of center when activity get loaded and add marker at the same time also.

You can use this code at any where you want after button click of activity creation time.

Comment: yeah you are right , but the problem is title("100 mi") is visible only after clicking at center. but i need to make it visible automatically.

Comment: this is ok but not exactly what i want.